# Mac - Unable to remove directory

Tags: macos, mac, osx-yosemite

I've been having great difficulty removing a directory from my external hard drive on my mac, I'm out of ideas now and was hoping someone here would be able to shine a light on this.

---

Here are some of the things I've tried:

**1) Deleting the file and emptying the Trash folder**

I get the message "The operation can't be completed because the item "folder" is in use."

**2) Securely emptying the Trash folder**

Same message as above.

**3) Using Terminal to navigate to Trash and using the command rm -rfv ***

Command runs, file is still there. Oddly, running "ls" shows that the directory isn't in the Trash folder but I can still see it in Finder.

**4) Moved the file back into its original location and running rm -rfv * there**

I get the message: "rm: folder/: Directory not empty"

I open the directory in finder, there is nothing there. I "cd" into it and can see one file (and it's not a dot file) in there.

Attempt to remove this file, and I get: "rm: file.ext: No such file or directory".

So I try this: "echo Hello > file.ext", now in Finder and when I view the contents of the directory in Terminal, I see TWO file.ext.

Proceed to removing this file, it removes one of them, the original file is still there.

I check my permissions of the directory and file, for my directory I have all permissions to read, write and execute (drwxrwxrwx) but I can't check the file because apparently it does not exist.

---

Any solutions out there? I don't really want to install any freeware to force delete it (it probably won't be able to anyway).

Comment: did you try rebooting yet? Running Disk Utility over the drive?

Comment: I can't confirm that at all. I'm on Yosemite too, if I put something to the Trash, it ends up in my `$HOME/.Trash`. That folder has the mode 700, along with the "deleted" files there is a file `.DS_Store`. And I can delete all with just `rm -rf .Trash`.

Comment: @Tetsujin Did you mean to run Disk Utility to format my hard drive? No doubt, that would probably work, but it's not practical for a 2TB hard drive.

Comment: @ott-- Sure, any other file would be deleted like that no problem. There's something peculiar about this particular file, it seems to exist but doesn't at the same time.

Comment: You can also try the `fuser` and `lsof` utilities to find out the process the are using that directory.

Comment: I meant to verify/repair the volume